# How can i DrawString each line in another color?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The rule is simple:

First line in Red second line in Green third line in Red.
I have a variable called m_text and it's format look like this:

[image: m_text format]

The first line in red the second line which is time&date in green.
Then there is an empty/space line then third line in Red fourth line in Green then empty/space line.
And the same for all the lines. The first in red second in green and then each line in red and green red green red green.

The variable _colors is Color[]

In the UserControl code top i did:

```
Color[] _colors;
string[] m_text = new string[0];
```

Then:

```
public void ScrollerColors(Color[] colors)
        {
            _colors = colors;
        }
```

Then:

```
public Color[] ColorLines
        {
            get
            {
                return this._colors;
            }
            set
            {
                this._colors = value;
            }
        }
```

Then the text to scroll:

```
public string TextToScroll
        {
            get 
            {
                return string.Join("\n", m_text);
            }
            set 
            {
                string buffer = value;

                m_text = buffer.Split(new char[1] { '\n' });
            }
        }
```

Then inside OnPaint event i have:

```
private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), this.ClientRectangle);

            int visibleLines = 0;

            Font drawFonts1 = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


            for (int i = m_text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {

                Point pt = new Point((int)((this.ClientSize.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(m_text[i], m_font).Width) / 2),
                    (int)(m_scrollingOffset + this.ClientSize.Height - (m_text.Length - i) * m_font.Size));

                if ((pt.Y + this.Font.Size > 0) && (pt.Y < this.Height))
                {
                    visibleLines++;
                }
                if (_colors != null)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(m_text[i], drawFonts1, new SolidBrush(_colors[i % _colors.Length]), pt);
                }
            }
```

The DrawString line also color the lines in m_text in red and green.

And this is how i'm using it in form1:

In top of form1:

```
scroller1.TextToScroll = combindedString;
ListColors();
```

combindedString is the text that will be in m_text.

Then in form1 in the bottom i have this method:

```
private void ListColors()
        {
            List<Color> allColors = new List<Color>();
            KnownColor[] colors = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
            foreach (KnownColor knowColor in colors)
            {
                Color color = Color.FromKnownColor(knowColor);
                allColors.Add(color);
            }
            scroller1.ColorLines = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Green };
        }
```

The result i get after using the DrawString is:

[image: DrawString result]

The DrawString color the first line in Red second line in Green then space/empty line then the fourth line in in Green but it should be in Red.

It should be like this:

Text line ( first line ) in Red then date&time line in Green.
Empty line....
Text line ( fourth line ) in Red then date&time line in Green.

How can i fix it ?

EDIT

This is what i changed in the OnPaint event:

```
if (_colors != null)
                {
                    if (m_text[i].Length > 0)
                    {
                        coloring += 1;
                    }
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(m_text[i], drawFonts1, new SolidBrush(_colors[coloring % _colors.Length]), pt);
                }
```

coloring is int.

But still im getting two lines in red two in green.

Tried also Vincent solution:

```
if (m_text[i] == string.Empty)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(m_text[i], drawFonts1, new SolidBrush(_colors[i % _colors.Length]), pt);
                    }
```

But what i get is:

[image: DrawString]

Comment: FYI, regarding your first screenshot - [You can use the snipping tool to capture context menus](http://blogs.technet.com/b/migreene/archive/2007/05/12/how-to-use-the-snipping-tool-to-capture-context-menus.aspx) like the one you have. It would probably be more readable than the current picture.

Answer (score 0):

The empty lines are included in m_text, so they use up the instance of red (3rd line, for example) or green (6th line, for example). You can use a different variable than i for `new SolidBrush(_colors[i % _colors.Length])`, and increment it only when the length of m_text[i] is greater than zero.

Comment: xpda i tried now please look at my question at the bottom i added what i tried now but still it's not working as excepted.

Comment: I'm not sure about the string length in c# -- is a null zero character included in the length? If so, check to see if it's > 1. If not, maybe there are some other non-printing characters in the empty strings, such carriage return, line feed, tab, space, etc. Maybe use the trim function?

Answer (score 0):

you want content line in Red and time date line in Green,and you use a Foreach key word to control alternative color , but you ignore one thing !!!,

their is string empty in your array

text line -- red

data & time line -- green

"" -- string empty you set to red

text line -- green !!

data & time line -- red !!

you can use if keywords to judge, if (m_text[i] == string.Empty) then ignore or jump this line.

Comment: Vincent i tried this: if (m_text[i] != string.Empty)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(m_text[i], drawFonts1, new SolidBrush(_colors[i % _colors.Length]), pt);
                    } but not working each two lines in red then two in green.

Comment: Vincent updated my question again with what i tried and a screenshot of what i get.

Comment: Please try change code to if(m_text[i].Length <= 0) { continue ;} , and y'd better set a break point to watch ,whether this if keyword run?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this constant format (red line, green line, empty line) ? why don't you just use 3 colors !?

let's say red, green, white, red, green, white, red .....

if you changed it to this stream I believe the empty string (internally) would like to be printed in `white` but oopsss there is no string! :D so it just jumps to the `next` string and `next` color which is definitely the loved `RED` ET VOILA!

**EDIT 1** Another approach:
I just noticed that you may get rid of your empty line by simply jumping of its index inside your loop while painting :

```
for (int i = m_text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
if((m_text.Length-i)%3 == 0) continue;
// keep the other part of your loop untouched

}
```

this loop will treat 1st and second lines and skips 3rd and so on
can you try it and feed-us-back :)

Comment: chouaib i tried it before adding another color make all the text to blink.

Comment: what do you mean by blink? does it switch unstably between red-green-white ?